# preg_match+multi patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to change this code

```
$reg_exUrl = "/imageshack/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $imageURL, $url))
```

so it will check fro more than one site, like

```
"/imageshack/,/photobucket/";
```

I'm noob in php!

Comment: try $reg_exUrl = "/imageshack|photobucket/";

Comment: preg_match uses Perl compatible regexp syntax, so what you're looking for here is not PHP related but rather a regexp syntax, which is a language on its own.

Answer (score 7):

In regular expressions, to select an option of multiple choices, use the `(|)` snytax:

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(imageshack|photobucket)/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $imageURL, $url))
```

Notice how the `/` are only regex delimiters, not part of the matched pattern.

Comment: If you are interested in doing this, but not creating a capture group, use `"/imageshack|photobucket/"`